# Not calling Elasticsearch and Database during assets precompile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch

When I do assets:precompile on my Rails project, seems like it would also call elasticsearch and my database connection. Is there a way to stop that as what I want is only assets compilation, it should not involve Elasticsearch and my database server.

PS: You may wonder why. That would be useful when you are developing the front-end and have to test it on a remote server. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try with this command in your console to stop elastic search. Hope it works.

```
sudo service elasticsearch stop
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions! The problem is on Rails side. I don't understand why it would try to access to the Elasticsearch. Since my ES runs remotely, it then became quite slow.

Comment: It seems there might be a problem with indexing. Try re-indexing your models.

Comment: I think the problem is whenever you run something with rails (rake or rails), it will start the ES client. I guess it would be a setting problem.